# How to reset Jtable, after search

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I am trying to reset Jtable after search. I manually set the field values to empty, but it is still not working.

Don't know what I am missing.

Comment: please share the relevant code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#your_table_container_ID td").parent().remove();
```

> This will remove all the records in a jtable but keeps the table
>   structure.

Comment: Besides the strange formatting (no need to ">" quote your explanation) this one reads way better ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I needed something similar today and not having the luxury of time on my side I implemented the following in a rush to get the job done (assuming i understood Kokirala Sudheer's need correctly):

> 1. Created a JS function which hosted my $('#mycontainer').jtable({ ... }) creation:

```
function jTable_Createtable()
{
    $('#mycontainer').jtable({
        title: 'my title...',
        paging: true, //Enables paging
        // etc......
    });

    // Can reload the grid here as well with "default" data.
    // $('#mycontainer').jtable('load');
}
```

> 2. Added the following function which even though it's not pretty, destroys the table and recreates it again using the function in 1 above:

```
function jtable_Reset()
{
    $('#mycontainer').jtable('destroy');
    jTable_Createtable();
}
```

Like I said it's not pretty or the optimized solution (which is what I normally go for), but it's efficient enough for a "quick fix".

I couldn't find an extension to the original jTable that does this in a sophisticated way so maybe a future side project...